# Como capturar los datos de una tabla con React.js y Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

Estoy creando una tabla en la cual mostrare diferentes productos y necesito tener la opcion de editar cada producto. Todos estos productos están almacenados en el store de redux, entonces lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar el botón de editar muestre el evento en active. (Adjunto imagen para que me entiendan mejor en donde quiero que el evento se muestre). Bueno el problema es que no se como puedo capturar los datos.

Como pueden ver lo que necesito es que en el campo active se muestre la data del objeto 0 cuando presione el boton de editar, pero no se como capturar los datos.

[image: Evento]

**Archivo donde renderizo la tabla**

```
   <div className="mt-5">
        
    <h1>Listado de productos</h1>
    <hr/>

    <input 
        type="text"
        className="mb-2 form-control"
        placeholder="Buscar producto"
    />

    <hr />

    <button 
        className="btn btn-primary"
    >
        Anteriores
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button 
        className="btn btn-primary"
    >
        Siguientes
    </button>

    <button
        className="btn btn-outline-success float-end"
        onClick={ handleAgregar }
    >
        Agregar
    </button>

    <hr/>

    <table className="table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style={{ width: 100 }}>ID</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Nombre</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Precio</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Stock</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Proveedor</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {body && body.map( b =>   
                <tr key={b.id}>
                    <td>{b.id}</td>
                    <td>{b.nombre}</td>
                    <td>{b.precio}</td>
                    <td>{b.stock}</td>
                    <td>{b.proveedor.nombre}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm">Editar</button>
                        &nbsp;
                        <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Los datos del store los obtengo mediante un useSelector y luego los coloco en la tabla.

```
  const { body } = useSelector( state => state.coffe );
```

Comment: Estás usando alguna librería para la tabla o lo estás haciendo desde cero? Si es el caso sería bueno que compartieras el código donde renderizas la tabla para así ser mas precisos con la ayuda que te podamos dar.

Comment: @guadamuzjj Ya actualice el post bro. La tabla la hice con bootstrap, ahora lo que necesito es que al presionar el boton de editar, es que muestre el evento seleccionado en el campo de "active" en el store.